# the command \par does not work?

Tags: formatting, packages

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\begin{document}
\section{Prove 1}
\begin{flushleft}
Def.: let be \( \mathfrak{m}: x \to \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{P}(x))\), \( \mathfrak{m} \) is topology on \( x \) if \par
1) \( x \neq \emptyset \) \par
2) \( \forall a \in x (x \in \mathfrak{m}(a) )\) \par
3) \(\forall a \in x (\forall t \in \mathfrak{m}(a)( a \in t))\) \par
4) \( \forall a \in x(\forall r,s \in \mathfrak{m}(a)((r \cap s) \in \mathfrak{m}(a) ))\) \par
5) \( \forall a \in x( \forall t \in \mathfrak{m}(x)(\exists r \in \mathfrak{m}(x)(\forall y \in r(t \in \mathfrak{m}(y)))))\) \par
6) \( \forall a \in x(\forall t \in \mathfrak{m}(x)(\forall r \subseteq x(t \subseteq r \to r \in \mathfrak{m}(x)))) \)
\section{Prove 2}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

the pdf is following:

[image]

Because the command `\par` doesn't work?

Comment: Why don't use `enumerate`?

Comment: @Marienplatz, how to do ?

Comment: `\begin{enumerate} \item \end{enumerate}`

Comment: `\par` is working, it's just that `flushleft` sets the paragraph indentation to 0pt. (However in this case, as has already been mentioned, you want the `enumerate` environment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own documentclass

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\section{Prove 1}

Def.: let be \( \mathfrak{m}: x \to \mathcal{P}( \mathcal{P}(x))\), \( \mathfrak{m} \) is topology on \( x \) if 
\begin{enumerate}[1)]
\item \( x \neq \emptyset \) 
\item \( \forall a \in x (x \in \mathfrak{m}(a) )\) 
\item \(\forall a \in x (\forall t \in \mathfrak{m}(a)( a \in t))\)
\item \( \forall a \in x(\forall r,s \in \mathfrak{m}(a)((r \cap s) \in \mathfrak{m}(a) ))\) 
\item \( \forall a \in x( \forall t \in \mathfrak{m}(x)(\exists r \in \mathfrak{m}(x)(\forall y \in r(t \in \mathfrak{m}(y)))))\) 
\item \( \forall a \in x(\forall t \in \mathfrak{m}(x)(\forall r \subseteq x(t \subseteq r \to r \in \mathfrak{m}(x)))) \)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not consider whether or not your math expressions should  get more correction (such as replacing the nested braces with something like `\left(...\right)`) as I am not competent in your field.

Comment: IMO no braces are needed at all.